# Form (phpmailer) in joomla error

Tags: forms, joomla, joomla2.5

I'm having the following problem, i created a folder (named 'forms') to storage the files of phpmailer, then i have to put the action in the form this way: action="forms/mail.php".

But when i tried the form it open a not found page e in the url it appears this: "perfilo/index.php/forms/mail.php", i tried to delete the part "index.php/" and execute the script and it looks like would work without it.

Can anyone tell me how to get rid of this "index.php/" part? Am i doing something wrong or what?

Thanks

Comment: wht you want exaclty ? send an email ? why you store the phpmailer files in your custom folder joomla has already phpmailer facility.

Comment: Ok, i guess i expressed myself in the wrong way. I have a contact page with a form using the phpmailer, in this form i have the action "mail.php", when i test the form it gives me an error and the url looks like what i put in the question.

Comment: In joomla we are not explicitly give file name as action.for example if your using com_contact component the your for action should be like index.php?option=com_contact&controller=contact&task=myfunc&view=contact and then write your action inside myfun() in contact controller page. I hope you got it?

Comment: I'm not using any component installed in joomla, just phpmailer and pure html in an article. My contact form it's like this "<form action="libraries/phpmailer/mail.php" method="post">" the part "libraries/phpmailer/mail.php" is the problem, when i execute the form it gives me a 404 error and the url looks like "index.php/libraries/phpmailer/mail.php". If i remove the "index.php" part and reload the page, it works. That's my question, why this index.php part is getting in the way and how to remove it.

Comment: WHy not just use the Joomla api that is already set up for interacting with whatever phpmailer? Using the API is not the same thing as using the contact form although you certainly could copy and paste from there.  Use the API don't fight with it.

Comment: But still, i used before without the API and worked, why now it's not working, i tried some components, but i prefer to do this way, and now i would like to understand how to make i work without a joomla API or component.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the wrong track.

Search for documentation on using Joomla! Mailer.

**Some resources to get you started:**

[JFactory/getMailer](http://docs.joomla.org/JFactory/getMailer)

[How To Send Email from Your Joomla Extension](http://www.ostraining.com/blog/how-tos/development/how-to-send-email-from-your-joomla-extension/)

Comment: It's a contact form in the site that i'm working with, i have already made one form the way i have explained above, unless i'm forgetting something.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the wrong path.

In joomla you need to implement a contact form.You can implement it like following.

Joomla Provides you a default component com_contact Any of the files from com_contact\views\contact\tmpl\ or you can create new layout with your custom design.

And you can access the files in url via wwww.domain.com/index.php?option=com_contact&view=contact&layout=default or your custom layout.

then joomla itself providing some forms if you want to customize that you can do that too.

The action they set in the form to contact controller. and sending the mail.

I got your point of view you are trying to create custom design and set it as article .
If you want to follow your own method.

You can work like this.
the form action leave as empty.
and onclick you have to set the action via jquery and then submit

Hope this may solve your issues

Comment: Thanks, but I've just solved the issue, i needed to add "../" to back one folder and it worked, at least it looks like. Anyway thanks for your answer, if anything wrong happens i will try what you and the others suggested.

Comment: @marcelosan People with experience are telling you that you took the wrong path and you keep it your way? Do you want to learn to write quality solutions or do you just want some crap that works?

Comment: @Valentin Despa I'm not trying to act like a stubborn one (although sometimes i am) i simply have no way to research this now, as i am new to joomla, i could put it running to show a preview of it, later when i have more time to concentrate on this i will come back and do what you experts told. It's just a 'crap that works' for my boss see it running.